# Is it good practice to create a new script for each new game object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity ( <200 hours) and I don't know what the proper practice is regarding when to create a new script vs. modify an old one.

For example:
My UI elements all share a script which has booleans for 'isSlider' and 'isButton', etc.
This toggle is used to activate or deactivate unique functions depending on the type of UI element while reusing some generic functions used across all of them.

Would it be better practice to create a new script for each UI element and just copy the generic code or is it okay to have toggleable functions to modify the functionality in the inspector.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

in OOP, you want to abstract functionality, rather than put it all under the same class

Look at the principle of single responsability: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle

it states that each class should be responsible for a single unit of functionality, therefore buttons and sliders should be different classes

if you have some generic it would make sense to share between all components, you can make your ui elements inherit of a parent class that handles that logic, for that, look at the concept of abstraction: https://www.guru99.com/java-data-abstraction.html